# Brachistochrone Problem Query

Tags: calculus-of-variations

In recent Calculus of Variations lecture, I learnt about the Brachistochrone problem and its solution. For those who don't know, it is a standard problem in dynamics which is often used as a motivating example in introductions to functional analysis. It goes as follows:

$\textbf{The problem}$

Suppose that a bead slides on a frictionless wire in a vertical plane. What shape of the wire minimises the time for the bead to fall from rest at a point $A$ to a lower, and horizontally displaced, point $B$?

$\textbf{Textbook solution}$

Choose $A$ to be the origin of coordinates in the vertical plane with x being horizontal distance from the origin and y being the distance below the origin. The bead starts with zero velocity so conservation of energy implies that its speed $v$ at any later time is given by $v=\sqrt{2yg}$, where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. Hence we have to minimise

$$T=\int_{A}^{B}\frac{dl}{v}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}}\int_{A}^{B}\frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{\sqrt{y}}$$

For simplicity, let us assume that $x$ is a good coordinate on the curve, so that $y=y(x)$ and

$$T=\int_{0}^{x_B}\sqrt{\frac{1+(y')^2}{y}}dx$$

To extremize $T$, we can use the Euler-Lagrange equations. As the integrand has no explicit $x$ dependence, these equations reduce to

$$C=\sqrt{\frac{1+(y')^2}{y}}-y'\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+(y')^2}{y}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y[1+(y')^2]}}$$

where $C$ is a constant. The resulting differential equation is $y[1+(y')^2]=2C$, where $C$ is a positive constant. This is well-known to describe a cycloid, i.e. the path traced by a point on the rim of a circle as the circle rolls along a straight line without slipping. It can further be show that the solution is given parametrically by $x=C(\theta-\sin\theta)$, $y=C(1-\cos\theta)$.

Now, this is where I am a little puzzled. All we have shown so far is that the functional $T$ is stationary when $y$ is a cycloid, and yet every single source I have found online claims that $y$ is an $\textit{absolute minimum}$ of $T$. Is this due to a misunderstanding on my part, or is this assertion indeed non-trivial and needs proving?

Answer (score 3):

Right, it's non-trivial. To show the cycloid is the absolute minimum, you need to do more than solve the EL equations, just like with regular calculus, you have to do more than solve $f'(x)=0.$ The analogy in the Calculus of Variations is to work with the second variation (the analogy of the second derivative). You would have to show that the [second variation is strongly positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Variations_and_sufficient_condition_for_a_minimum).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. However, I am still somewhat confused.  Doesn't strong positivity only imply that the function is a local minimiser, as opposed to a global minimum?