# Curve of quickest descent....

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

The question states :
A curve of   quickest descent in the vertical plane, where $y$ is vertical and $x$ is horizontal, is the solution of the equation:

(a) $y(1+y'^2)=c$

(b)$\sqrt{y^2-c^2-y'}=c$

(c) $y'\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=\sqrt{x}$

(d) $y'\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=a$

I understood by curve of quickest desent they mean brachistochrone curve, which is the cycliod..so we are supposed to check which of the following differential equation gives the cycliod as solution, I think..

But then finding solution of all this diffferentail equation is also not easy..

Is there a better way to deal with this question...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Brachistochrone Problem Query](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309729/brachistochrone-problem-query)

Comment: $\implies dt = \frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{\sqrt{2g(y_0-y)}} dx$. Then apply the Euler-Langrange equations. Haven't done that part yet, but I"M thinking it would be (a).

Comment: From where u got the equation $dt=\frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{\sqrt{2g(y_0-y)}}dx$.